# Can't find class with BS4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Can't find a class

```
url = "https://elektro-ufa.ru/product-category/avtomobilnye-aksessuary/?per_page=-1"
responce = session.post(url, headers = header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup (responce, 'lxml')
block = soup.find("div", class_="products elements-grid wd-products-holder  elements-list products-bordered-grid wd-quantity-enabled pagination-pagination align-items-start row")
print(block)
```

I don't understand what's wrong

You need to get the name of all the elements
This query outputs the following: None
[Finished in 6.5s]

Answer (score 0):

Use `multi_valued_attributes=None` in `BeautifulSoup` constructor if you want to use bs4 API and multi valued attributes (like attribute `class_=` in this example with multiple classes). Alternative is to use `.select_one` with CSS selector:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'
}

url = "https://elektro-ufa.ru/product-category/avtomobilnye-aksessuary/?per_page=-1"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup (response, 'lxml', multi_valued_attributes=None)
block = soup.find("div", class_='products elements-grid wd-products-holder  elements-list products-bordered-grid wd-quantity-enabled pagination-pagination align-items-start row')
print(block)
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="products elements-grid wd-products-holder  elements-list products-bordered-grid wd-quantity-enabled pagination-pagination align-items-start row" data-columns="4" data-max_price="" data-min_price="" data-source="main_loop">
<div class="product-grid-item product product-list-item wd-quantity  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 first  last  type-product post-173230 status-publish first instock product_cat-fm-modulyatory-bluetooth-aux-adapter has-post-thumbnail shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" data-id="173230" data-loop="16">
<div class="product-wrapper">

...
```